# Revoking token for client credentials grant laravel passport

Tags: laravel, oauth, jwt

I'm using laravel passport for machine2machine api. Requesting an access_token through 'oauth/token' endpoint does not make the previous access_token invalid so how do i revoke/delete the token for client credentials grant ?

Comment: are you usint auth:api middleware?

Comment: @hmrneves using the clients middleware just like in the docs

Comment: did you try ```$request->user()->token()->revoke();```?

Comment: @hmrneves how do i use user() since this is a machine 2 machine. there's no login

Comment: You can create your own 'oauth/token' implementation and revoke the old access_token.